# the uniqueness of the decomposition of a rank 1 PSD matrix into the product to two vectors

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, positive-semidefinite

If rank($X$)=1 and $X$ is positive semidefinite, then there exists $z\in\mathbb{R}_{n\times 1}$, such that $X=zz^T$.

My question is whether $z$ is unique?

Comment: $zz^T=(-z)(-z)^T$.

Comment: @user1551 Other than $-z$, is it possible to exist other solution? Thanks

Comment: Think about the range of $X$.

Comment: @M.K Assume that there are $y, z$ such that $X = yy^\top = zz^\top$. We have $yy^\top z = z z^\top z$. Thus, $y = \alpha z$. Thus, $\alpha^2 = 1$.